# How to deal with <%= text_field %> in ruby on rails when javascript is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I used the JavaScript as:**

script language="javascript"

function writeResult(text){
    document.myform.tDescription.value = text;

}

/script

**hence my text field will be:**

form="myform"
 <%= s.text_field 'xyz','abc',  :name =>('tDescription'), :size =>50 %>
/form

I have to store this text value in the table 'xyz' in column 'abc' but its not working. As ruby on rails by default take the text field name as **name="xyz[abc]"** , if i m not specifing any name for the text field but becoz of java script the function call I have specify the name as **tDescription**.
Please help how I can store this value in database.
If i use **input tag** instead. What will the controller corresponding code.

Comment: maybe, at first, you should have a look at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#top to get a first feel about how rails apps get created and bonded to a database ... as actually if that is all done and working you won't need to ask how to store data into your database as rails will take care of that for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give your textfield a unique id

```
<%= s.text_field 'xyz','abc', :id => "tdescription", :size =>50 %>
```

now you can have your javascript refer to the id and let rails use name for its uses

either go by classic javascript

```
getElementById('tdescription')
```

or my preference use jquery

```
$('#tdescription')....
```